# React - Local storage stopped working after changing code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, store

I use a React application where I use hooks, local storage and React, the context of the problem is that my local storage stopped working after some code changes in the old version, everything worked for me after I decided to get rid of the duplicate code.Local storage stopped working my old code looks like this [enter link description here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SuroZaqaryan/Portfolio_v_1.0/master/src/components/Content/Courses/Lessons/components/Theme/ThemeDoc.js)

This is how my code looks now

```
export const CounterContext = createContext([]);

export default function ThemeDoc(props) {

    const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("SideBarKey"));
    const [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground] = useState(localStorage.getItem("BgKey"));

    // SideBar Wallpapers
    const [SideBarBackgrounds,] = useState([
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Bg,
        },
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Pink,
        },
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Anapa,
        },
    ])

    // Gradient Themes
    const [GradientThemes,] = useState([
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(66, 116, 131, 1) 0%, rgba(69, 75, 88, 1) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(65,116,130,1) 0%, #353a4f 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, #51adff, #10f4a0)",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #33b7de",
        },
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(146 93 116) 0%, rgb(71 75 88) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(147 99 123) 0%, rgb(55 58 80) 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(120deg,#ffb2b2 0,#f68084 100%)",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #ff8185fa",
        },
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(96 110 150) 0%, rgb(69 75 88) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(94 110 149) 0%, rgb(53 58 80) 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, rgb(48 137 198), rgb(161 186 255))",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #818db0",
        },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('SideBarKey', JSON.stringify(SideBarTheme));
        localStorage.setItem("BgKey", SideBarBackground);
    })

    const ChangeSideBarWallpaper = (SideBarWallpaper) => {
        localStorage.setItem('BgKey', SideBarWallpaper);
        SetSideBarTheme(localStorage.removeItem("SideBarKey"));
        SetSideBarBackground(SideBarWallpaper);
    }

    const SideBarPageContent = (PageContent, SideBar, TextColor) => {
        localStorage.setItem('SideBarKey', JSON.stringify({PageContent, SideBar, TextColor}));
        SetSideBarTheme({PageContent, SideBar, TextColor});
    }

    const gradientList = GradientThemes.map((gradTheme, index) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                key={index}
                style={{background: gradTheme.RadioButtonBackground, border: gradTheme.RadioButtonBorderColor}}
                className={"RadioButton_ThemeDoc"}
                name="group1"
                value="first"
                onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(gradTheme.PageContent, gradTheme.SideBar, gradTheme.TextColor)}
            />
        );
    })

    const SideBarWallpaperList = SideBarBackgrounds.map((theme, index) => {
        return (
            <img key={index} width={"52"} height={"42"} src={theme.SideBarWallpaper} className={"SideBar_Appearance_Select_Icon"}
                 onClick={() => ChangeSideBarWallpaper(theme.SideBarWallpaper)} alt={"Select Theme"} />
        );
    })

    return (
        <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
            <CounterContext.Provider value={{
                SideBarValue: [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme],
                SideBarWallpaperValue: [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground],
            }}>
                <SideBar gradientList={gradientList} SideBarWallpaperList={SideBarWallpaperList} {...props} />
                <PageContent {...props} />
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your setting the state initially, there is no null check because of that might cause the issue.

If you clean the browser cache then you don’t find the key in local storage or in any other browser.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Verify the life cycle once where your are setting and getting, check the localstorage value are getting and setting properly

Answer (score 0):

```
export const CounterContext = createContext([]);

export default function ThemeDoc(props) {

    const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SideBarKey")));
    const [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground] = useState(localStorage.getItem("BgKey"));

    // SideBar Wallpapers
    const [SideBarBackgrounds,] = useState([
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Bg,
        },
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Pink,
        },
        {
            SideBarWallpaper: Anapa,
        },
    ])

    // Gradient Themes
    const [GradientThemes,] = useState([
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(66, 116, 131, 1) 0%, rgba(69, 75, 88, 1) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(65,116,130,1) 0%, #353a4f 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, #51adff, #10f4a0)",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #33b7de",
        },
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(146 93 116) 0%, rgb(71 75 88) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(147 99 123) 0%, rgb(55 58 80) 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(120deg,#ffb2b2 0,#f68084 100%)",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #ff8185fa",
        },
        {
            SideBar: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(96 110 150) 0%, rgb(69 75 88) 100%)",
            PageContent: "linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(94 110 149) 0%, rgb(53 58 80) 80%)",
            TextColor: "#dfdfdfb3",
            RadioButtonBackground: "linear-gradient(40deg, rgb(48 137 198), rgb(161 186 255))",
            RadioButtonBorderColor: "1px solid #818db0",
        },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('SideBarKey', JSON.stringify(SideBarTheme));
        localStorage.setItem("BgKey", SideBarBackground);
    })

    const ChangeSideBarWallpaper = (SideBarWallpaper) => {
        localStorage.setItem('BgKey', SideBarWallpaper);
        SetSideBarTheme(localStorage.removeItem("SideBarKey"));
        SetSideBarBackground(SideBarWallpaper);
    }

    const SideBarPageContent = (gradTheme) => {
        localStorage.setItem('SideBarKey', JSON.stringify(gradTheme));
        SetSideBarTheme(gradTheme);
    }

    const gradientList = GradientThemes.map((gradTheme, index) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                key={index}
                style={{background: gradTheme.RadioButtonBackground, border: gradTheme.RadioButtonBorderColor}}
                className={"RadioButton_ThemeDoc"}
                name="group1"
                value="first"
                onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(gradTheme)}
            />
        );
    })

    const SideBarWallpaperList = SideBarBackgrounds.map((theme, index) => {
        return (
            <img key={index} width={"52"} height={"42"} src={theme.SideBarWallpaper} className={"SideBar_Appearance_Select_Icon"}
                 onClick={() => ChangeSideBarWallpaper(theme.SideBarWallpaper)} alt={"Select Theme"} />
        );
    })

    return (
        <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
            <CounterContext.Provider value={{
                SideBarValue: [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme],
                SideBarWallpaperValue: [SideBarBackground, SetSideBarBackground],
            }}>
                <SideBar gradientList={gradientList} SideBarWallpaperList={SideBarWallpaperList} {...props} />
                <PageContent {...props} />
            </CounterContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```